# Read an array from the end

Tags: c

I am working on a piece of C programme.

I have a loop for which I am iterating over a certain value over time. For example, the value ranges from 0.1 to 1 and time ranges from 0 to 2. I iterate over time for the value = 0.1 and so on for the rest of the values. I store the output in an array, for example:

```
value = 0.1 
time    parameter1    parameter2
```

So, my code gives me two arrays of the known size (2/stepping_in_time+1). The numbers for parameter1 fluctuates between negative and positive values until a moment where it constantly falls below 0.2. What I want to have is that moment.

To obtain that, I need to read the result of the array from the end of the array, that is I want to go through the array from end until I reach to number 0.1 for the first time, I want to print that time instance.

I would appreciate any comment on how this can be done.

Comment: Please show the "piece of C program" (code) that you've been working on.

Comment: Sorry for not putting the code because this is an assignment of the course I am taking and I was afraid if I write the code, the C experts will directly give me the solution, but I want to work on it myself, I just need some hints on how to tackle such a problem.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell you what you're doing wrong, when you don't tel us what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"To obtain that, I need to read the result of the array from the end of the array, that is I want to go through the array from end until I reach"

Since you filled the array, yoyu know its size.
You just need a pointer on the last element of the array and decrement it until you find the value you want.

something like (pseudo C..) :

```
float *lastElem;
float myArray[255];

lastEslem = myArray[254];
while(lastElem-- != 0.1)
{
  //Do something or not
}
//lastElem is now on the searched value.
return lastElem;
```

Answer (score 0):

loop over the array, and note down (temp var) where you first see a .1.  If you come across a value > .1, clear the location.  At the end, the temp var will contain the location of the first .1 of the trailing sequence of values <= .1, or will be empty if there was none.